# How is Netty server able to identify which client the response needs to be sent to?

Tags: netty, nio

I have a simple Netty server that listens for Http requests and upon receiving a request, sends back the response by adding some headers.

The scenario that I created is as follows:

I have two browser tabs firing requests to the server one after the other, in such a manner that the second request is fired only after the first response is received.

I observe that the channel used to service both the requests is the same.
I fail to understand, how does Netty identify which client to respond to? On what basis is the distinction made between both the requests and the source of both these requests?

Comment: Can you please share a full reproducible code?

Comment: The code is added at: https://github.com/krishnadwypayan/Netty-Http-Server/tree/master

Comment: As you said that the browser is firing request one after another and channel is same, this means that browser is using same connection to make requests from 2 tabs. This is connection pooling commonly used by a client(browser). Now if the browser makes http/1.1 request then client can send a request and wait for response before initiating a new request. Netty pipeline writes the payload on a socket(tcp/ip). OS prepares the packets/frames and sends it to destination IP and port number. A unique machine is identified by IP and process on a machine is identified by port# it is listening to.

Comment: Thanks @SivapraneethAlli for your reply.
Also, would like to ask if there is anything that distinguishes two different Netty requests.

Comment: @KrishnaDwypayan I really did not understand what you meant by Identifying two requests. Http itself is a stateless protocol. Unless you use http session(or something similar) you cannot co-relate two requests. Do this help?

Comment: Also will add that when a second request is made, the browser must have identified that an idle connection already exists(in connection pool) to the host and used the same connection instead of creating a new connection. This is likely because client did not close the connection after first request. If you add `ChannelFutureListener:CLOSE` then a new connection will be created for second request. HTTP/1.1 states that a connection can be used for multiple requests and when client wants to close connection a Connection header with close as value has to be sent in request. Default is keep-alive